# Sentence-transformer module not found when running flask app

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, conda, sentence-transformers

I'm working on a flask app to deploy my NLP model which will be linked to a front- and backend later on. This is my flask_app.py code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import joblib
import pandas as pd
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

app = Flask(__name__)

# Load the model from .joblib file
with open("API/NearestNeighbors_clf.joblib", "rb") as file:
    loaded_model = joblib.load(file)

# load the database from .csv file
df = pd.read_csv("DL/database_Leo.csv")

# define embedding model based on all-MiniLM-L6-v2
model = SentenceTransformer('sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2')
model.max_seq_length = 512  # Change the length to 512

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route("/predict", methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    # extract input data from the request
    star_rating = float(request.form["star_rating"])
    price = float(request.form["price"])
    user_input_str = str(request.form["user_input_str"])

    # create embeddings for user input
    user_input_emb = model.encode(user_input_str).reshape(1,-1)

    # make prediction based on user input
    distances, indices = loaded_model.kneighbors(user_input_emb)
    # flatten indices array to use as index in dataframe
    indices = indices.flatten()

    # get ID's to return
    recs = df.iloc[indices]["reference"]

    return jsonify({"recommendations" : recs})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I tested the imports and the models separately and everything is working perfectly fine, but when I run the whole file, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phyla\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-79851fa29ea7>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:\\Users\\phyla\\Documents\\Github\\ss23-drop-in-to-berlin\\API\\flask_app.py', wdir='C:\\Users\\phyla\\Documents\\Github\\ss23-drop-in-to-berlin\\API')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:\Users\phyla\Documents\Github\ss23-drop-in-to-berlin\API\flask_app.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.1.3\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sentence_transformers'
```

I'm not sure if it has to do with the way that I installed sentence_transformers, but it does show up in my conda environment (which is active) and as I said everything works until I try to run it as flask app.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by myself. I thought it might help others, so I will leave the answer here:

running the flask app via the terminal command:

```
flask --app flask_app.py run
```

Was the key I was missing.